# adding a hdfs datanode in a running spark/hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a spark cluster with 1 master and 2 nodes (worker + datanode).
    I want to add another datanode.
    the problem is, when i do `hdfs dfs -setrep -R -w 2` ,the result is :

```
    1st datanode -> DFS Used%: 75.61%
    2nd datanode -> DFS Used%: 66.78%
    3rd datanode -> DFS Used%: 8.83%
```

do you know how to do to manage to balance blocks in hdfs in order to be 30 -> 33% each approximatly?

Thanks

Comment: You should set three replicas so that all three datanodes get used.

Answer (score 1):

Run [`balancer`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#balancer), the cluster balancing utility. This will rebalance the data across the datanodes.

```
hdfs balancer -threshold <threshold_value>
```

`-threshold` determines the percentage of disk capacity. The default value is 10.

This specifies that each DataNode's disk usage must be or should be adjusted to be within 10% of the cluster's overall usage.

This process might take longer time depending upon the amount of data to be balanced and does not affect the Cluster operations.

Or, Perform Datanode [Commissioning](https://acadgild.com/blog/commissioning-and-decommissioning-of-datanode-in-hadoop/) if adding additional nodes are opted.